# Vue js conditional layouts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I have a vue js app utilizing vuetify layout. The main points of interest look as follows:
**main.js**

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import { App } from './app'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import('../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css')

/* eslint-disable no-new */

Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import routes from '../app/routes'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes
})
```

**app/index.js**

```
export { default as routes } from './routes'
export { default as vuex } from './vuex'
export { default as App } from './App'
```

**app/routes.js**

```
import accounts from './accounts/routes'
import budgets from './budgets/routes'
import transactions from './transactions/routes'

import IndexComponent from './IndexComponent'

var rt = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: IndexComponent,
    name: 'index'
  }
]

export default [...rt, ...accounts, ...budgets, ...transactions]
```

**app/App.vue** (basically is layout now)

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire" dark="">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      clipped=""
      fixed=""
      v-model="drawer"
      app="">

      <v-list dense="">

        <v-list-tile :to="{name: 'index', params: {id: 'test'}}">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>home</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Home</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile :to="{name: 'accountsListView', params: {id: 'add'}}">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>dashboard</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Tester</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile @click.stop="dialog = true">
          <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="290">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title class="headline">Use Google's location service?</v-card-title>
              <v-card-text>Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.</v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="dialog = false">Disagree</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="dialog = false">Agree</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>settings</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Settings</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar app="" fixed="" clipped-left="">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Lost Memories</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>

    <router-view />

    <v-footer app="" fixed="">
      <span>&copy; 2018</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null,
    dialog: false
  }),
  props: {
    source: String
  }
}
</script>
```

**app/IndexComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid="" fill-height="">
        <v-layout justify-center="" align-center="">
          <v-tooltip right="">
            <v-btn icon="" large="" :href="source" target="_blank" slot="activator">
              <v-icon large="">code</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span>Source</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
  }),
  props: {
    source: String
  }
}
</script>
```

**app/accounts/routes.js**

```
import * as components from './components'

export default [
  {
    path: '/accounts',
    component: components.AccountsListView,
    name: 'accountsListView'
  },
  {
    path: '/accounts/create',
    component: components.CreateEditAccounts,
    name: 'createAccounts'
  },
  {
    path: '/accounts/edit',
    component: components.CreateEditAccounts,
    name: 'editAccounts'
  }
]
```

And then some dummy account components. So as expected on home page IndexComponent takes place of a `route-view` and is rendered as expected. There are 2 main problems that i'm facing at the moment:

1. How can I conditionally change the layout with vue? For example, if the user is not authenticated then I’d like to redirect him to another view with different layout. How can I replace the current layout? Is it even possible with the architecture like that?
2. On home page the `Home` link is highlighted with blue (as an active) and that's correct, but when I visit other urls like `/account` then both links are highlighted in the tools menu, did I setup routes incorrectly or there is some other reason for that?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Answer (score 3):

For authentication, I use vue-router's per-route guard `beforeEnter`, ref [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

Authguard just checks the Vuex store for a valid user, but you can use any expression in the if..else block.

```
{ path: '/tasks', name: 'Tasks', component: Tasks, 
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (AuthGuard.canActivate()) {
      next()
    } else {
      next({ path: `/login?returnUrl=${to.path}&prompt=Team Tasks` })
    }
  } 
},
```

Note when not logged in, I take them to the login page but also pass a returnUrl so that after successful login they come back to the original requested page.

The Login.vue component handles returning like so

```
created() {
  this.returnUrl = this.$route.query.returnUrl
}
methods: {
  login() {
    // record the user details
    if (this.returnUrl) {
      this.$router.push(this.returnUrl);
    }
  },
}
```

---

Re active links, in a standard vue nav you would use

```
<router-link to="/tasks" tag="li" active-class="active"><a>Team Tasks</a></router-link>
```

where the active-class attribute takes care of putting `active` (for bootstrap) on only one link.

I don't know how you'd do it for your nav, perhaps look for something similar in vuetify.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful chunk of information, however what if it’s not the auth case but generally another app section that requires another layout?